# How can I use a variable used in a function for something outside of that function?

Tags: c#, variables

I'm somewhat of a beginner to C# and basically I'm trying to make a simple program that allows you to click on buttons to randomize the race and class of your character. Surprisingly, actually setting up the randomizer wasn't the problem. I successfully created the program but then to make it more complex I added a picture box that would display an example of that randomization. Basically I set it up like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var r = new Random();
        var classText = r.Next(1, 7);
        if (classText == 1)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Mage";
        }
        else if (classText == 2)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Rogue";
        }
        else if (classText == 3)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Ranger";
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var r2 = new Random();
        var raceText = r2.Next(1, 10);
        if (raceText == 1)
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Human";
        }
        else if (raceText == 2)
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Dwarf";
        }
        else if (raceText == 3)
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Elf";
        }
    }

    if(classText == 1 && raceText == 1)
    {
        pictureBox2.ImageLocation = whatever;
    }
    else if (classText == 1 && raceText == 2)
    {
        textBox2.Text = "Elf";
    }
    else if (classText == 2 && raceText == 3)
    {
        pictureBox2.ImageLocation = whatever;
    }
    etc........
```

The last if statement, however, does not work because the variables I used are not accessible outside of their respective functions. I need a way to be able to use those variables in the if statement so that I can tell it which picture to put there. Is there anyway to 'return' a variable like in python or is there a better way?

Comment: Not related to your question but I would strongly recommend that you learn about `enum`s.  You should define an `enum` for class and another for race.  You can then convert your random numbers directly to enumerated values and assign them directly to variables or properties of that type.  They give you the advantages of using strings, the advantages of using integers and more besides.

Answer (score 2):

This is all about scope, which you should do some reading on.  Basically, a variable only exists inside the block in which it's declared.  If you declare a variable inside a method then it only exists inside that method.  If you want to be able use a variable outside a method then it must be declared outside that method.  If you want to use the same variable in multiple methods then it must be declared outside all of them, i.e. at the class level.

Comment: With that in mind, you shouldn't be declaring a separate `Random` variable in each method and creating a new `Random` object each time.  That has potential issues.  You should declare one variable at the class level and create one object, then use them each time.

Comment: I tried that but whenever I declare a var at class level it says "the type or namespace var could not be found". Do I need to be using those enum things for this to work?

Comment: You can only use `var` within a method. For fields at the class or struct level you need to be explicit about the type yourself.

Comment: Okay well now I'm having a different problem. Instead of having "var r = new Random();" in the function, I have "Random r = new Random();" at class level. The new problem is that after replacing "var classText = r.Next(1, 7);" with "int classText = r.Next(1, 7);" it says that it can't reference the static field, method or property 'r'. What the heck do I do now?

Comment: Think about what you're doing.  Generate the random number when you need it.  Noone said to only generate a value for those variables once.  What was said that you declare the variables at the class level, not assign a value to them at the class level.  If you do that then they will only ever have one value and every player will be the same.  Declare the variables at the class level and set their values where you were in the first place.